# Why is my iPhone 4s Videos app displaying TV show episode and series titles as "Unknown" and Season as "(null)" and how do I fix it?

Tags: iphone

To restate the question, why is my iPhone 4s Videos app displaying TV show episode and series titles as "Unknown" and Season as "(null)" and how do I fix it?

I have already attempted to reboot, access the files directly in PhoneView, and through iTunes. I cannot make these dead files go away and syncing doesn't help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried completely turning off TV show syncing in iTunes?
Also maybe give deleting all your videos from within the settings app at Genereal > Usage and here look for the Videos app.

As a last resort remains always a complete iOS Restore using iTunes or the option in the iPhones settings app under General > Reset > Reset All Settings/Erase All Content and Settings. Make sure to either have a backup in your iCloud or on your computer using iTunes.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying not to restore if I don't have to. I realize that will fix (almost) everything that can go wrong with iOS, but I was hoping for a non-nuclear solution. I don't think there is a way to turn off TV Show syncing in iTunes or to delete videos from General > Usage, as there is no Videos app listed there.